# Measuring the bandwidth of an app for beginners

Tags: bandwidth

I have an app that streams audio/video and I want to measure the bandwidth that it needs. I have never done anything like this before. Can you very simply explain the process and tools needed to carry this out?

Comment: Do you want to measure it just once, at home, or live in the app, when it is installed (on what device?), or at the server, once, or at the server, when running in production use..? Please elaborate!

Comment: As you can see, I dont even have the knowledge to word the question specifically enough! 
I only want to measure it once, while the app is running, installed on a win7 machine. Both upload and download bandwidth (it does both at separate times).

Comment: You should be more clear on the questions. Do you want to measure the bandwidth a media require for perfect streaming? Do you want to measure the bandwidth utilization while streaming? Is that app is a program created by you?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Task Manager and in there select the Network tab.

There you will see the current and historic throughput for the last n seconds.